# Pretty print Xml input and output

Tags: xml, pretty-print, fitnesse

I have a decision table that accepts Xml as one of the input parameters, and returns Xml as one of the output parameters. For example:

```
!|FixtureThatUsesXml|
|request|fieldX|response?|
|<Xml><SomeContent a="1"/></Xml>|2| |
```

Is it possible to have the Xml in the request and response formatted (with syntax colouring and appropriate line breaks)? For the response, perhaps I could return text that is encoded to include the rich text formatting? What's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your (Slim) fixture output HTML. That will be used when displaying the response.

Having the request formatted is not that easy if you want to go beyond pre-formatted text, because you have to use the wiki formatting features and will have to remmove it in the fixture.

You can easily have pre-formatted XML in your wiki (by enclosing in `{{{` and `}}}`) which your fixture then would remove before actually using the XML. But highlighting etc in your requests is not easy to do.

The XML [fixtures I use](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures) do accept pre-formatted input and show responses formatted. But it is not as fancy as you describe (see [this sample test output](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.HttpTests.HttpPost1Test.html)).

Comment: Thank you for replying Fried. I tried including the `<pre>` tag in the output, but that resulting in nothing being displayed (potentially related to the `ignore` class applied to the `span`. I tried using `&nbsp;` but the content was escaped. Is there a special way to output HTML?

Also, I'm using a `!define` variable for my Xml so that my table row doesn't span multiple lines; my attempts of including `{{{ }}}` seem to have no effect other than to display the brackets. Even used directly on the table with and without `!- -!`; perhaps this is not supported in the latest version?

Comment: The sample I linked was using the latest FitNesse, so it is supported. Try enclosing the `<pre>` in a `<div>`. And to display XML in a HTML page you need to escape the XML (I use Apache Commons html escaping). Please look at https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/blob/master/wiki/FitNesseRoot/HsacExamples/SlimTests/HttpTests/HttpPost1Test/content.txt to see the `{{{ ` and ` }}}` in action.

Comment: Brilliant, the `<div>` worked perfectly! It turns out that if my table has the `!` (as in `!|FixtureThatUsesXml|`) the `{{{` does not work. I instead named my table in the form `Fixture That Uses Xml` and the `!` wasn't required.